# Some way to "pre-construct" query with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I'm developing a database application using Entity Framework 6. In one place, I need to assemble a query based on user input and then return that query to the caller. I can't run the query myself and return the result set because the caller needs to store the query to run again later if the UI is refreshed. I also can't return an `IQueryable` representing the assembled query because this is only valid for the context against which it was assembled.

I've looked at using `CompiledQuery.Compile` but this doesn't work with the `DbContext` base class in Entity Framework 6. I need to do something like that, pre-compiling/pre-assembling/pre-constructing a query that can be returned and run again later, but that works with Entity Framework 6. I don't care whether the query is returned in the form of a delegate or whatever, I just need something that represents the query independently of any specific context instance.

How can I pre-construct and return a query with Entity Framework 6 such that it can be run multiple times against different context instances?

Comment: precompiling past EF4 works with executing the query once - then the query is computed and cached. I don't think there will be a context independent solution though - your context contains mapping information that makes query calculation possible.

Comment: **All** queries are cached by Entity-Framework per Application Domain.  It doesn't matter what dbcontext you have, how many... etc it doesn't matter it will be cached until the engine determines it shouldn't or your application domain ends.

Comment: I'm not looking to cache the query specifically. Really I'm looking for a way to construct a query and return it from a function, then later execute it against a specified context.

Comment: I'm not sure a query makes sense independant of a context. Do all the possible contexts share a common type? Then you can use a lambda return.

Comment: @NetMage They're all instances of the same context class. What I want is to return a query designed to run against `MyDatabaseContext`, then when I load the UI I say `using (MyDatabaseContext context = new MyDatabaseContext())` and load the content for the UI using the query, then later when the UI is refreshed I want to again say `using (MyDatabaseContext context = new MyDatabaseContext())` and load the updated content using the same query as before (I can't reconstruct the query again at refresh because the query is constructed by the dialog that's long gone and is opaque to the caller).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was creating a delegate type to encapsulate the queries, that takes `MyDatabaseContext` as a parameter and returns a `List<T>` where `T` is the type of the particular entity that I'm querying for.

So now the function that creates the query can simply return a function and whenever the query needs to be run the query is simply called as a function passing it the context instance to act upon as a parameter. The function returns from the given context a list of entities as applicable for the query that it represents.